# How to change the directory of my own .sty files in MacOS?

Tags: packages, mactex, package-writing

Right now, I save my own packages in the shown 'standard' directory.

[image]

I can use this package in MacTeX  with a simple `\usepackage{}` command.

I want to backup my styles in iCloud without to copy it all the times. So I tried to create an alias but that is not working. Is there a way to change this directory?

Comment: You need to create a symbolic link using the terminal. Aliases are not quite the same thing.  See [Centralised .bib file on Mac](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/337952)

Comment: I think you can do this in the terminal: `TEXINPUTS="path/to/sty//:$TEXINPUTS"` before compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacOS aliases are not quite the same as symbolic links, so if you want to have your local `texmf` folder be somewhere else, you need to link it using a symbolic link.  So first move your existing `texmf` folder to some folder that iCloud syncs, e.g. your home `Documents` folder.

Then in the Terminal make a symbolic link:

```
ln -s ~/Documents/texmf ~/Library/texmf
```

(This assumes that  iCloud syncs your `Documents` folder.).

Now you just use the iCloud `texmf` folder and it will always be seen.

Comment: No, there is no `~/iCloud` folder

Comment: @egreg Oops.  So then you just make sure it's a folder in your Home that is synced. Does my edit address that?

Answer (score 5):

I did the following test in the Terminal (`bash` shell)

```
cd
ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs iCloudFolder
TEXMFHOME=~/iCloudFolder/texmf pdflatex test
```

(this temporarily overrides the inner variable `TEXMFHOME`) and got

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/Users/enrico2013/iCloudFolder/texmf/tex/latex/test.sty
FOUND
) (./test.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdf
tex.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 8685 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

on my console.

The file `test.tex` contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

whereas the `texmf/tex/latex` folder in the iCloud drive has `test.sty` which just contains

```
\typeout{FOUND}
```

As you see, the output is as expected.

Now just change the top level `texmf.cnf` file in `/usr/local/texlive/2018` from

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf
TEXMFVAR = ~/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = ~/Library/texlive/2018/texmf-config
```

to have

```
TEXMFHOME = ~/iCloudFolder/texmf
```

then copy `texmf` in `~/Library` to the iCloud drive.

Note that this makes no assumption on what you sync with iCloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `\makeatletter\def\input@path{{path/to/styfiles/}}\makeatother` before you do usepackage, but after `\documentclass`! Note the double `{{}}` and that the path ends with `/`!

E.g. if you have a directory called `stydir/` containing `mypack.sty` you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter\def\input@path{{stydir/}}\makeatother
\usepackage{mypack}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```