# Placing custom .sty files on a Dropbox directory

Tags: packages, texlive

I have recently switched computer (Mac OSVentura) and installed TexLive 1.54. I have my custom .sty files in a Dropbox directory which is sync across devices: ~/Dropbox/software/Tex/texmf/tex/latex/mytex.sty and it used to work without any issue. But now my latex editor (Texmaker) tells me it cannot find mytex.sty on the new computer. (no issue with TexLive packages) To be honest, I have forgotten whether I had to run some terminal command to make it work in the past.

I have looked at similar questions on the forum, but none seem to work for me.
FYI, if I run `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` I get `/Users/102666/Library/texmf` but I actually do not seem to find the directory in the Library, not even if I make hidden files visible. See screenshot. Not sure this is important because the idea was to have the files in a Dropbox directory.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: texlive sets TEXMFHOME under your home directory (or Library on macos) but doesn't actually make the directory it's just that if you make the directory there the files will be found. but you can add your dropbox folder to TEXINPUTS

Comment: you can probably add the dropbox texmf as a new tree with something like `tlmgr conf auxtrees add ~/Dropbox/software/Tex/texmf` (I'm not on a mac and I can't test how to handle the `~`, perhaps you will have to replace that by the real path).

Comment: Are you running on Apple Silicon or Intel? There was a change made to Dropbox on Apple Silicon which has numerous issues (I think this is Apple's fault as Dropbox is now required to use filprovider). If on Apple Silicon, one thing you could try is changing the path to `/Users/p/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/` instead of `~/Dropbox`.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I tried your suggestion in Terminal but got an error message `Cannot write to /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf: Permission denied`. Any idea?

Comment: @PeterGrill Hi Peter, yes I am running a Mac mini with an M2 pro processor (Apple silicon). I tried to follow your suggestion by creating a Dropbox folder in `/Library/CloudStorage` and added my `texmf/tex/latex/mytex.sty` file there, but it was not found when compiling a latex document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried to add my dropbox folder to TEXINPUTS using `TEXINPUTS=/Users/102666/Dropbox/software/Tex/texmf//:` in Terminal. There is no error message. But when I compile the .tex document it complains that it cannot find **mytex.sty**

Comment: I have now used a symbolic link with `ln -s ~/Dropbox/software/Tex/texmf ~/Library/texmf` in Terminal. This seems to work. I have picked this method from this post on StackExchange [How to change the directory of my own .sty files in MacOS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438800/how-to-change-the-directory-of-my-own-sty-files-in-macos)